# What does electron autoUpdater download?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

do not wish to download full application for a small update in electron application

I have found out that replacing the app.asar file in my electron app's resources directory , updates the "code-specific-updates" in my application , is this enough for an update or autoUpdater does something extra to update the application ?,

"code-specific-updates" refer to renderer and html changes
I have also tried using squirrel for windows , but cannot use it because it does not allow me to install application to custom directory (Program Files in my case)